# Opening a new browser window with specificed HTML

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

I have a webpage which dynamically creates markup within itself. On the click of a certain button I want a client-side event to 'copy' this markup and place it in the `<body>` of a blank page which it will open in a new browser window. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean "dynamically" using a server-side language?

Comment: wat do u mean by markup here?

Comment: Hi, no the page creates markup within itself on the client. It's actually creating a VML image (I'm using IE) - and it's also modifying the contents of a `<table>`. I want to to lift this image and table and open in a separate browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a new window, the function returns a "handle" to this window.

You can then manipulate the new window with javascript (so long as it points to a URL on the same domain).

```
var newWindow = window.open ("", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
newWindow.document.write("Hello world");
```

The `newWindow.document` gives you access to the DOM of the new window.

Comment: When you say 'manipulate' do you mean I can re-direct the new window to a different address? Or can I actually write markup to the new window?

Comment: Ok, I've managed to inject the markup but my VML is not rendering in the window even though if I view source it is there. Any ideas? Separate question I know...

Comment: @El Ronnoco - I am guessing it needs to be on the page as it loads and injecting might not work. However, you are better off asking it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

As you want it on the client-side using JavaScript (from your tags), you can use the `window.open`.

```
var w = window.open("", "Some Title");
w.document.body.innerHTML = "yay!";
```

Note that, in this example, the target inside `window.open` function is a blank string which means that the new window opened will be a blank window (not redirected to any URL like your website's).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I couldn't write directly to `body` as it doesn't yet exist.

Comment: It probably depends on the browser you are using. Firefox 3.6 automatically added a body element (with no content) to the new window.